# How Azure pipelines can get source from Internal TFS and External Git? How can I update the proxy?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pac

I am setting up Azure Pipelines, I have few that get sources from GitHub and trying to setup pipelines to reach TFS on Intranet, I created a Service Connection of type: “Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server” using this Other Git URL: `https://tfs.myCie.com/defaultcollection/MyProject/_versionControl`

When I run the pipeline, it takes some time then it displays a 504 Timeout error but the pipeline is still pending.  After a while, it goes into error with this message in the step “`Checkout repository@master to s`”:

```
git -c http.proxy="http://myProxy.myCie.com:80" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://tfs. myCie.com/defaultcollection/myProject/_versionControl/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to tfs.oecd.org:443 
##[warning] Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 3.667 seconds before retry.
```

Security team says that I should use a PAC file to setup the proxy and that should enable intranet and Internet calls but I don’t see how to update the proxy settings of my Self-Hosted Windows Agent.

Can I specify a file?  Can there be a configuration for Internet and another one for intranet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don’t see how to update the proxy settings of my Self-Hosted Windows
> Agent. Can I specify a file?

For the agent you need to create a .proxy file with the proxy URL in the root directory of your agent.

1. Locate the root directory of your build agent (this is the folder
   that contains the run.exe and the _work folder).
2. Open a Command Prompt at this location.
3. Type this command, but replace `PROXYIP & PORT` with your values:

   ```
   echo http://PROXYIP:PORT > .proxy
   ```
4. Check that your .proxy file is created at the right place:

   [image]
5. Optional: If your proxy needs authentication, you must set these
   environment variables:

   ```
   set VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME=user
   set VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD=password
   ```
6. Restart the service for your build agent.

When you know that you need a proxy at the time of the installation, you can configure the proxy settings right when you call config.cmd:

```
./config.cmd --proxyurl http://127.0.0.1:8888 --proxyusername "user" --proxypassword "password"
```

For details, please refer to this [blog](https://improveandrepeat.com/2020/01/how-to-configure-a-proxy-for-your-azure-devops-build-agent/).

Here is the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks !  I did use the Config command at first but then, I was told to use a PAC file to enable both Internet and intranet, can I use a PAC file that is on the intranet ?  Also, I looked at environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY, the value is not the same as in the .proxy file, can you tell in which cases the Env variables are used compared to the .proxy file ?

Comment: Also, for any distracted guy like me, when looking for .proxy* files, enable the show hidden files !! :-)